# Is there any way to revert the changes done by "drush cim"?

Tags: drush, configuration, importing-exporting

I usually take backup of the entire database before importing new configurations, but this time I didn't and now I need to double check something with old version of database. Is it possible to just revert the changes done by `drush cim`?

I am using Drupal 8.

Googling for this specific situation didn't give me any solution.

Comment: Configuration is saved in yml files inside the /config folder and not the database. If you use a version control system like GIT, you could see and also revert changes.

Comment: You might still need a database backup, reverting config doesn't restore deleted content.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't revert `drush cim` without a backup (or alternate config export) of some sort.  If you don't have a backup, you're out of luck.

One safety measure to prevent this kind of problem is to write a script that backs up your database and then calls `drush cim`.  Then, only run the script to do a config import, and you can ensure you have always made a backup first.

Comment: :( Thanks anyway!

Comment: Another safety measure is to use version control ;+)

Comment: @NoSssweat version control does not help at all since changes can originate from the UI, which are then overwritten by `drush cim`. Only safe way is to backup the config tables, or `drush cex` to export current state, store it (either in version control or as a zip) and then run `drush cim`.

Comment: No Sssweat is correct. He meant to do what most developers do for deployments which is to run drush cex to export your config.. and then, user version control to commit this config. So when you run cim and its not what you wanted; you can simply revert to an older version of your config; and cim that one.